# Get the plot I am looking at as a 300px TIFF for publication

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, tiff

I'm trying to solve a common problem for me. Once I have a plot (usually made using ggplot) then I need the output in a high res (300 or sometimes 600 dpi) TIFF image (in OSX).

I figure I could make a simple function for this, but it seems not to work the way I expected.

```
dev.copy2tiff <- function(filename,res=300,compression="lzw",...){
  sizes <- dev.size(units="px")

  cop <-dev.copy(tiff,filename=filename,width=sizes[[1]],height=sizes[[2]],units="px",res=res,compression=compression,pointsize = 3,...)
  dev.flush()
  dev.off()
  return(cop)
}
```

Output:

[image]

Screenshot of what the plot should look like:

[image]

Why are the output in the TIFF not like what is on the screen, and what can I do about it?

EDIT:

Just realized: the size of the device should of course be specified as width and height, not pixels. This revised code:

```
dev.copy2tiff <- function(filename,res=300,compression="lzw",...){
  sizes <- dev.size(units="cm")

  cop <- dev.copy(tiff,filename=filename,width=(sizes[[1]]),height=(sizes[[2]]),units="cm",res=res,compression=compression,...)
  dev.flush()
  dev.off()
  return(cop)
}
```

Produces a nicely looking TIFF image that looks like the one presented on the screen (in RStudio), but in 72 DPI (according to OS X Preview).

How come it's not 300 dpi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this seems to be to go through the EPS file format.

```
dev.copy2eps(file="filename.eps")
```

is now my friend. Once opened in Preview (OSX) it can be exported to TIFF (or submitted as is).